# Symfony2: Could not load type "MyType"

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to create a new field type and add it to a form class in Symfony 2.

I have created a class called `MyType` (for testing purpose) and when I want to add it to a form class I get the error:

> Could not load type "MyType".

I guess I must tell Symfony to load that type, but I don't know how!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have register your form in the section services of your config.yml

```
services:
   my_type_form:
      class: sf\MyTypeBundle\Form\MyType
      tags:
         -  { name: form.type }
```

Then you can call it from your controller with the name "my_type_form".

Comment: Actually, since that's a service, I'd rather declare it in the services.yml file